# How to set font size in Android webView fixed , even if font size changed in Settings->Display->Font?

Tags: android, web, webview

How to set font size in Android webView fixed, even if font size changed in Settings->Display->Font?

In the project, everything presented in the webView is under web development. So, font sizes are set by units of px and em, but not dp or sp. How to set up the font size so that they would NOT resize if the option of font size under Settings->Display->Font changed?

Please leave a comment if any code is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the FontSize in an Android WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796176/how-to-change-the-fontsize-in-an-android-webview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed text size in WebView Android (Lollipop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816804/fixed-text-size-in-webview-android-lollipop)